# Unity - Although there is no problem with APK Build, ABB build crashes

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, assetbundle

I am facing a strange problem in the project I created with Unity 2022.3.1. Our project has been around for a long time, we wanted to give an update after approximately 45 days of work. Although there is no problem in any of the tests we made as an APK, we always receive a Crash error when we upload our game to Google Play.

Even though I tried with a completely empty new test scene, the error was not resolved. Additionally, I removed all SDKs in the project. (Firebase, Facebook, Vivox)

The error code I receive when I log in to the game is as follows:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: AssetPackBackgroundExecutor
> Process: com.games.hon, PID: 11180
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/tasks/TaskCompletionSource;
> at com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.aw.d(com.google.android.play:asset-delivery@@2.0.0:3)
> at com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.l.f(com.google.android.play:asset-delivery@@2.0.0:2)
> at com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.i.run(Unknown Source:2)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.tasks.TaskCompletionSource
> at com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.aw.d(com.google.android.play:asset-delivery@@2.0.0:3) 
> at com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.l.f(com.google.android.play:asset-delivery@@2.0.0:2) 
> at com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.i.run(Unknown Source:2) 
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)

I tried reimporting all assets, I tried deleting folders such as "Library, Temp" in the project folder. The problem was not solved in any way. I will try to upgrade the Unity version, as I understand there is a problem with the "AssetBundle" connection. While there is no problem with APK, a problem occurs when ABB creates it (I know Unity does this with the asset bunde plugin). Maybe upgrading the Unity version will also change the Asset Bundle infrastructure. I'll post updates here after I upgrade.

Thanks.